# Run tcp server in another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I'm struggling with running tcp server in  different thread. So I have sth like that:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

std::string make_daytime_string()
{
    using namespace std; // For time_t, time and ctime;
    time_t now = time(0);
    return ctime(&now);
}

class TcpServer
{
private:
    boost::asio::io_context& io_context_;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;
    
public:
    TcpServer(boost::asio::io_context& io_context)
        : io_context_{io_context}
        , socket_(io_context_)
        , acceptor_(io_context_, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 512))
    {
        acceptor_.accept(socket_);
        std::string message = make_daytime_string();

        boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
        socket_.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(message), ignored_error);
    }
};


int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context io_cont;
    std::thread t([&io_cont] ()
    {
        TcpServer server(io_cont);
    });

    std::cout << "I want to display it while server is still running";

    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Basically this TcpServer is running all the time until it gets connection, sends datetime and then exits.
What I want to do is:

1. Run the server
2. Keep processing my things in main function
3. Send command `nc 127.0.0.1 512`
4. program ends

Comment: It appears to work correctly while I'm trying other things. Any idea why the std::cout is delayed till the end of `t1` ?

Comment: I have trouble understanding what precisely the difference between the current and the wished behaviour is. - From reading your source code currently your code should do two things at the same time: 1) The main thread outputs a message to console. 2) The thread `t` opens a new connection, blocks until somebody connects to it (e.g. by opening a client from console with `netcat`) and then sends it the current daytime as a string. Then the program ends. Is the code behaving differently? Is this not how it should behave?

Comment: Use `std::endl` or `std::flush` to flush IO

Comment: @2b-t my apologies, maybe I didn't write it clearly enough. I want the program to block after my `std::cout` . At this moment it is blocking before even though I'm first performing stdout and then join.

Comment: As @sehe pointed out you will have to flush the output with `std::endl`: Modify `std::cout << "I want to display it while server is still running";` to `std::cout << "I want to display it while server is still running" << std::endl`.

Comment: okay that explains why the program behaves as expected, just doesn't print on time. Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some confusion about using `io_context`; You seem to think operations run on the context, but they won't **unless** you use `async_` versions.

Other side notes:

- write_some doesn't (need to) send the whole buffer. Use `boost::asio::write` instead.

Here's a simpler example that clarifies the confusion:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49f59d874ed00b21)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

static std::string make_daytime_string()
{
    using namespace std; // For time_t, time and ctime;
    time_t now = time(0);
    return ctime(&now);
}

class TcpServer {
  public:
    void run() {
        tcp::acceptor acceptor_(io_context_, {{}, 5120});

        boost::system::error_code ec;
        while (!ec) {
            auto socket_ = acceptor_.accept();
            std::string message = make_daytime_string();
            boost::asio::write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(message), ec);
        }
    }
  private:
    boost::asio::io_context io_context_;
};

int main()
{
    auto server = TcpServer{};
    std::thread t([&server]() { server.run(); });

    for (;; std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s))
        std::cout << "I want to display it while server is still running" << std::endl;

    t.join();
}
```

Prints

```
./a.out& for a in {1..9}; do sleep .5; nc 127.0.0.1 5120 <<< ''; done
kill %1
I want to display it while server is still running
Mon May 24 17:41:35 2021
I want to display it while server is still running
Mon May 24 17:41:35 2021
Mon May 24 17:41:36 2021
I want to display it while server is still running
Mon May 24 17:41:36 2021
Mon May 24 17:41:37 2021
I want to display it while server is still running
Mon May 24 17:41:37 2021
Mon May 24 17:41:38 2021
I want to display it while server is still running
Mon May 24 17:41:38 2021
Mon May 24 17:41:39 2021
```

Comment: 1. If I'm correct the io_context is required for constructor of many objects so even if I don't use it I must specify it? 2. Despite the fact my code is ugly it should work properly? I mean why the `std::cout` appears after I send request with netcat?

Comment: 1. You don't use the polling interface, but the objects use the "execution context" to get service implementations from, so yeah you need then. Note, most service objects take **executors**, not just io contexts, and that's a better way to decouple your code anyways.

Comment: 2. No, your code didn't run on a separate thread at all. I explained that was because you don't use async operations, meaning, the calls inside the constructor were all blocking on the main thread.

Comment: now I'm more confused than I used to be. Async i/o is different topic than multithreading, isn't it? Are constructor calls (even though it was inside new thread) always mainatained by main thread or what is going on?

Comment: Yes, and yes. Constructors are just functions. They happen to be called in some context  but it's still code running on the same thread.

Comment: That's very important to know. I greatly appreciate your time spend on helping and answering my questions. But why calling class constructor isn't running in different thread and class method is? (According to the difference between our code samples.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232831/discussion-between-sehe-and-robert-kwiatkowski).